# Sencha TextField in NestedList header

Tags: filter, textfield, sencha-touch, nested-lists

Is it possible to add filter text to NestedList's header? You can see what exactly I mean here:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?130609-Filter-text-in-NestedList

I would like to create a search functionality on NestedList. Whe user would insert character it would create a RPC call and return search result.

Is that possible to create and if yes - how?

best

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can [set the `toolbar`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/source/NestedList.html#cfg-Ext.NestedList-toolbar) property on the NestedList when you create it to customise it. You don't have to worry about the `back` button as the NestedList will add this in for you.